# ReactJS: Hard-coded state with array, but still getting TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I hard-coded the following array named searchResults just to test:

```
function App() {
  const [searchResults, setSearchResults] = useState([{
    name: 'Jamming',
    artist: 'Bob Marley',
    album: 'Jamming',
    id: 0
  }, {
    name: 'Paradise',
    artist: 'Coldplay',
    album: 'One',
    id: 1
  }]);
  const [playlistName, setPlaylistName] = useState('My Playlist');
  const [playlistTracks, setPlaylistTracks] = useState([{
    name: 'Jamming',
    artist: 'Bob Marley',
    album: 'Jamming',
    id: 0
  }]);

  function addTrack(track) {
    if (playlistTracks.some(el => el.id !== track.id)) {
      setPlaylistTracks(playlist => [...playlist, track]);
    } else {
      alert('Track already in the playlist');
    }
  }

  function removeTrack(track) {
    let result = playlistTracks.filter(el => el.id !== track.id);
    setPlaylistTracks(result);
  }

  function updatePlaylistName(name) {
    setPlaylistName(name);
  }

  function savePlaylist() {
    const trackUris = playlistTracks.map(track => track.uri);
  }

  function search(term) {
    console.log(term);
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Ja<span className="highlight">mm</span>ing</h1>
      <div className="App">
        <SearchBar onSearch={search} />
        <div className="App-playlist">
          <SearchResults 
            searchResults={searchResults} 
            onAdd={addTrack} 
          />
          <Playlist 
            playlistName={playlistName} 
            playlistTracks={playlistTracks} 
            onRemove={removeTrack} 
            onNameChange={updatePlaylistName} 
            onSave={savePlaylist}
          />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

I'm passing the searchResults all the way from App.js to TrackList.js. So from App to SearchResults component:

```
import React from 'react';
import './SearchResults.css';
import TrackList from '../TrackList/TrackList';

function SearchResults({ searchResults, onAdd }) {
  return (
    <div className="SearchResults">
      <h2>Results</h2>
      <TrackList searchResults={searchResults} onAdd={onAdd} isRemoval={false} />
    </div>
  );
}

export default SearchResults;
```

And then finally reaching TrackList. If I comment out in my TrackList.js where I map through it, I can see the searchResults arrive correctly there:

[image]

[image]

[image]

If I uncomment the line where I do the maping, I get the error below:

```
import React from 'react';
import './TrackList.css';
import Track from '../Track/Track';

function TrackList({ searchResults, playlistName, playlistTracks, onAdd, onRemove, isRemoval }) {
  return (
    <div className="TrackList">
      {searchResults.map(track => <Track key={track.id} track={track} onAdd={onAdd} onRemove={onRemove} isRemoval={isRemoval} />)}
    </div>
  );
}

export default TrackList;
```

[image]

Can anyone see where I got his wrong? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you also include your `SearchResults` component code, and *any* components between that and `TrackList` where the error is occuring?

Comment: Add a conditional rendering. The searchResult is not initialized yet when you try to render it.

Comment: Hey Drew, I edited the question better now.

Comment: @yAzou but I already declared its value up there, before it renders.

Comment: That all looks ok, and seems to work as expected here in this [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/beautiful-knuth-ii1wu?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&module=%2Fsrc%2FApp.js&theme=dark). Perhaps there is more going on that *isn't* in any of your snippets. It's possible `setSearchResults` is setting the state to something other than an array. Can you share a running codesandbox that reproduces the issue?

Comment: @DrewReese is right I also tried in my editor and it works well

Comment: @DrewReese second this, I suspect he has a lifecycle hook between state and the return statement (see `........` above) that is updating state perhaps. OP, can you share entire code snippet?

Comment: Hey guys, thanks for the quick feedback. I added the whole components now to the question. Didn't add in the first place as I thought it would be too long, but already updated there.

Comment: SearchResult && SearchResult.map , be carefully this is props render first time don't understand it is array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the issue, thanks for everyone that tried to help the newcomer here.

TrackList has 2 parent components, SearchResults and Playlist. I was passing the states searchResults and playlistTracks down with different names, and only maping the searchResults array.

So it was simply a matter of having the same name for both props before they reached TrackList, which I named **tracks**.

In my Playlist component: `<TrackList tracks={playlistTracks} />`

And in my SearchResults component: `<TrackList tracks={searchResults} />`

So they both arrive in Tracklist as **tracks**, then I can map: `{tracks.map(track => <Track key={track.id} track={track} onAdd={onAdd} onRemove={onRemove} isRemoval={isRemoval} />)}`

Answer (score 0):

```
<div className="TrackList">
{searchResults && searchResults.length && searchResults.map(track => <Track key={track.id} track={track} onAdd={onAdd} onRemove={onRemove} isRemoval={isRemoval} />)}
</div>
```

Comment: Pls add some description to your answer and explain how it works and solves the problem.

Answer (score -1):

You need to check before render

```
function TrackList({ searchResults, playlistName, playlistTracks, onAdd, onRemove, isRemoval }) {
  return ({typeof searchResults !== 'undefined' &&
    <div className="TrackList">
      {searchResults.map(track => <Track key={track.id} track={track} onAdd={onAdd} onRemove={onRemove} isRemoval={isRemoval} />)}
    </div>
  });
}
```

Comment: Not useful, `searchResults` is initialised as an array.

Comment: @lawrence-witt did you try it? because of the asynchronicity in React and JS, the first call the state will not have value jet.